# magento final_price,min_price,max_price wrong values insertion

Tags: magento

Hi 
i have problem with the final_price,min_price,max_price in the catalog_product_index_price table its is wrongly inserting the values after function save() during import.
The file is app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Convert\Adapter\Product.php
The control goes to finish() function

```
public function finish()
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_import_after', array());

    $entity = new Varien_Object();
    Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction(
        $entity, self::ENTITY, Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE
    );
}
```

where is the insert statement to insert the value in the catalog_product_index_price table?
How this can be resolved?

My saveRow fucnction to populate database.My excel sheet contains the following additional row 
Price Type:radio:1

### Unit Price:absolute:2691|Case Price:absolute:12420

### Unit Price:absolute:762|Case Price:absolute:7029

The save database function is

```
public function saveRow(array $importData)
{
$product = $this->getProductModel()
->reset();

if (empty($importData['store'])) {
if (!is_null($this->getBatchParams('store'))) {
$store = $this->getStoreById($this->getBatchParams('store'));
} else {
$message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skipping import row, required field "%s" is not defined.', 'store');
Mage::throwException($message);
}
}
else {
$store = $this->getStoreByCode($importData['store']);
}

if ($store === false) {
$message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skipping import row, store "%s" field does not exist.', $importData['store']);
Mage::throwException($message);
}

if (empty($importData['sku'])) {
$message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skipping import row, required field "%s" is not defined.', 'sku');
Mage::throwException($message);
}
$product->setStoreId($store->getId());
$productId = $product->getIdBySku($importData['sku']);

if ($productId) {
$product->load($productId);
}
else {
$productTypes = $this->getProductTypes();
$productAttributeSets = $this->getProductAttributeSets();

/**
* Check product define type
*/
if (empty($importData['type']) || !isset($productTypes[strtolower($importData['type'])])) {
$value = isset($importData['type']) ? $importData['type'] : '';
$message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skip import row, is not valid value "%s" for field "%s"', $value, 'type');
Mage::throwException($message);
}
$product->setTypeId($productTypes[strtolower($importData['type'])]);
/**
* Check product define attribute set
*/
if (empty($importData['attribute_set']) || !isset($productAttributeSets[$importData['attribute_set']])) {
$value = isset($importData['attribute_set']) ? $importData['attribute_set'] : '';
$message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skip import row, the value "%s" is invalid for field "%s"', $value, 'attribute_set');
Mage::throwException($message);
}
$product->setAttributeSetId($productAttributeSets[$importData['attribute_set']]);

foreach ($this->_requiredFields as $field) {
$attribute = $this->getAttribute($field);
if (!isset($importData[$field]) && $attribute && $attribute->getIsRequired()) {
$message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skipping import row, required field "%s" for new products is not defined.', $field);
Mage::throwException($message);
}
}
}

$this->setProductTypeInstance($product);

if (isset($importData['category_ids'])) {
$product->setCategoryIds($importData['category_ids']);
}

foreach ($this->_ignoreFields as $field) {
if (isset($importData[$field])) {
unset($importData[$field]);
}
}

if ($store->getId() != 0) {
$websiteIds = $product->getWebsiteIds();
if (!is_array($websiteIds)) {
$websiteIds = array();
}
if (!in_array($store->getWebsiteId(), $websiteIds)) {
$websiteIds[] = $store->getWebsiteId();
}
$product->setWebsiteIds($websiteIds);
}

if (isset($importData['websites'])) {
$websiteIds = $product->getWebsiteIds();
if (!is_array($websiteIds)) {
$websiteIds = array();
}
$websiteCodes = explode(',', $importData['websites']);
foreach ($websiteCodes as $websiteCode) {
try {
$website = Mage::app()->getWebsite(trim($websiteCode));
if (!in_array($website->getId(), $websiteIds)) {
$websiteIds[] = $website->getId();
}
}
catch (Exception $e) {}
}
$product->setWebsiteIds($websiteIds);
unset($websiteIds);
}
$custom_options = array();
foreach ($importData as $field => $value) {
if (in_array($field, $this->_inventoryFields)) {
continue;
}
if (in_array($field, $this->_imageFields)) {
continue;
}

$attribute = $this->getAttribute($field);
if (!$attribute) {
/* CUSTOM OPTION CODE */
if(strpos($field,':')!==FALSE && strlen($value)) {
$values=explode('|',$value);
if(count($values)>0) {
@list($title,$type,$is_required,$sort_order) = explode(':',$field);
$title = ucfirst(str_replace('_',' ',$title));
$custom_options[] = array(
'is_delete'=>0,
'title'=>$title,
'previous_group'=>'',
'previous_type'=>'',
'type'=>$type,
'is_require'=>$is_required,
'sort_order'=>$sort_order,
'values'=>array()
);
foreach($values as $v) {
$parts = explode(':',$v);
$title = $parts[0];
if(count($parts)>1) {
$price_type = $parts[1];
} else {
$price_type = 'fixed';
}
if(count($parts)>2) {
$price = $parts[2];
} else {
$price =0;
}
if(count($parts)>3) {
$sku = $parts[3];
} else {
$sku='';
}
if(count($parts)>4) {
$sort_order = $parts[4];
} else {
$sort_order = 0;
}
switch($type) {
case 'file':
/* TODO */
break;

case 'field':
case 'area':
$custom_options[count($custom_options) - 1]['max_characters'] = $sort_order;
/* NO BREAK */

case 'date':
case 'date_time':
case 'time':
$custom_options[count($custom_options) - 1]['price_type'] = $price_type;
$custom_options[count($custom_options) - 1]['price'] = $price;
$custom_options[count($custom_options) - 1]['sku'] = $sku;
break;

case 'drop_down':
case 'radio':
case 'checkbox':
case 'multiple':
default:
$custom_options[count($custom_options) - 1]['values'][]=array(
'is_delete'=>0,
'title'=>$title,
'option_type_id'=>-1,
'price_type'=>$price_type,
'price'=>$price,
'sku'=>$sku,
'sort_order'=>$sort_order,
);
break;
}
}
}
}
/* END CUSTOM OPTION CODE */
continue;
}

$isArray = false;
$setValue = $value;

if ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'multiselect') {
$value = explode(self::MULTI_DELIMITER, $value);
$isArray = true;
$setValue = array();
}

if ($value && $attribute->getBackendType() == 'decimal') {
$setValue = $this->getNumber($value);
}

if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

if ($isArray) {
foreach ($options as $item) {
if (in_array($item['label'], $value)) {
$setValue[] = $item['value'];
}
}
} else {
$setValue = false;
foreach ($options as $item) {
if ($item['label'] == $value) {
$setValue = $item['value'];
}
}
}
}

$product->setData($field, $setValue);
}

if (!$product->getVisibility()) {
$product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
}

$stockData = array();
$inventoryFields = isset($this->_inventoryFieldsProductTypes[$product->getTypeId()])
? $this->_inventoryFieldsProductTypes[$product->getTypeId()]
: array();
foreach ($inventoryFields as $field) {
if (isset($importData[$field])) {
if (in_array($field, $this->_toNumber)) {
$stockData[$field] = $this->getNumber($importData[$field]);
}
else {
$stockData[$field] = $importData[$field];
}
}
}
$product->setStockData($stockData);

$imageData = array();
foreach ($this->_imageFields as $field) {
if (!empty($importData[$field]) && $importData[$field] != 'no_selection') {
if (!isset($imageData[$importData[$field]])) {
$imageData[$importData[$field]] = array();
}
$imageData[$importData[$field]][] = $field;
}
}

foreach ($imageData as $file => $fields) {
try {
$product->addImageToMediaGallery(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import' . trim($file), $fields);
}
catch (Exception $e) {}
}

$product->setIsMassupdate(true);
$product->setExcludeUrlRewrite(true);

$product->save();
/* Remove existing custom options attached to the product */
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
$o->getValueInstance()->deleteValue($o->getId());
$o->deletePrices($o->getId());
$o->deleteTitles($o->getId());
$o->delete();
}

/* Add the custom options specified in the CSV import file */
if(count($custom_options)) {
foreach($custom_options as $option) {
try {
$opt = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option');
$opt->setProduct($product);
$opt->addOption($option);
$opt->saveOptions();
}
catch (Exception $e) {}
}
}

return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This section of the code has been quite well tested, so it's unlikely (though conceivable) that this is a bug that you need to correct in the indexer. Can you provide more detail about the discrepancy that you are seeing?

There is a very good chance that you are seeing unexpected results because of some product being enabled/disabled, etc etc.